# CAS logout not working when deploying to different machines

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

If I use CAS server and my application in the same machine, logout is working fine for me. But if CAS server is deployed on the different machine and my application is deployed on the different machine, then cas logout is not working. 
I am calling the following url from my application:

```
CAS Server URL: https://108.51.62.36:9443/cas/logout
```

And I have got the following entries in web.xml of my application:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Included to support Single Logout. Note that the SingleSignOutFilter 
    is included in the springSecurityFilterChain. However, it could also be placed 
    as the first filter-mapping in the web.xml -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whe you use CAS, this create a secure cookie domain. You can see the value and modify in WEB-INF/spring-configuration:

- ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator.xml
- warnCookieGenerator.xml

So, I suggest don't use Ip. Use another like https://my.domaing.com:9443/cas/logout