# CAS SingleSignOutFilter

Tags: java, cookies, single-sign-on, cas, jsessionid

I followed the [CAS Best Practices](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Best+Practice+-+Setting+Up+CAS+Locally+using+the+Maven+WAR+Overlay+Method) for building a `cas.war` (v4.0.0) and deploying it to Tomcat7. When I spin up Tomcat, I am able to access my CAS login page at:

```
https://localhost:8443/cas/login
```

I then deploy one of my "client" apps (a Grails web app using Shiro for authentication), which comes online at:

```
http://localhost:9100/myapp
```

I go to an authenticated URL for `myapp`:

```
http://localhost:9100/myapp/secret
```

I am successfully redirected to my CAS login page (for now, I'm using the default `casLoginView.jsp`). I check my browser cookies, and for the CAS site I have a `JSESSIONID`. I login using the CAS default credentials (username is *casuser*; password is *Melon*) and am successfully redirected to `http://localhost:9100/myapp/secret`. Great success! I check my cookies again and see that I have the same `JSESSIONID` as well as a new `CASTGC` cookie.

I now go directly to my CAS logout page:

```
https://localhost:8443/cas/logout
```

I see a "Logout successful" message, and check my cookies again. The `CASTGC` cookie is gone, and I still have a `JSESSIONID`, however, it's a different `JSESSIONID` than the first one I got.

I now go back to my authenticated URL:

```
http://localhost:9100/myapp/secret
```

I expect to be redirected to the CAS login page: instead I am allowed to view the `/secret` page and **appear to still be authenticated, even after logging out!!!**

I *believe* I need to implement the `SingleSignOutFilter` by placing it in `myapp`'s `web.xml` as [instructed here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Single+Sign+Out).

#### What I need to know:

- Will configuring `SingleSignOutFilter` in `web.xml` complete my implementation for single sign out, or is there more config that I need to do?
- Once single sign out is implemented, will it have the expected behavior that I describe above? Meaning, if I go to the `/logout` link, then anytime I try to go to an authenticated URL, it should redirect me back to the `/login` page?
- How can I tell which protocol (CAS 2.0 or SAML 1.1) I'm using? I should be using whatever default CAS 4.0.0 ships with as I didn't override anything in my project.
- What is the difference between `JSESSIONID` and `CASTGC`? How are they handled/used different by the server?
- Do I need to configure anything in `cas-servlet.xml` to get single sign out working? If so, what? If not, what is this file used for?

Comment: Have you tried searching SO for other answers? There are about a dozen questions on this exact topic.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerDollery (+1) - however the only question I can find that is relevant to single sign **out** (not sign *in*!) is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258113/cas-logout-not-working?rq=1), which was caused by the user using an IP address instead of a fully-qualified domain name for their CAS server.

Comment: I should also mentions that this happpenns regardless of whether I am running CAS locally (`localhost`) oor if I deploy it to our DEV environment (`dev.mycas.example.com`, etc.).

Comment: And please note, this also happpens with CAS 3.5.2.1 (the latest/stable release) as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cas+single+sign+out or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cas+sso

Comment: _What is the difference between JSESSIONID and CASTGC? How are they handled/used different by the server?_                                                                 CASTGC cookie is used by CAS server to establish that user has a valid SSO session. So it's validity spans across apps that user can access through SSO.                                                                                      While JSESSIONID is between user and a specific casified app and used by the app to establish that user has already validated with it.

Answer (score 2):

> #### What I need to know:
>
> - Will configuring `SingleSignOutFilter` in `web.xml` complete my
>     implementation for single sign out, or is there more config that I
>     need to do?

Yes, definitely. But for avoiding leaking resources, you should follow the guides and also add a `SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener` to your web.xml. See the [official Java client documentation](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#configuring-single-sign-out) for a complete setup on the client side. Don't forget to switch the Github page to whichever CAS client version you use. (And beware that it might contain typos.)

> - Once single sign out is implemented, will it have the expected
>     behavior that I describe above? Meaning, if I go to the `/logout`
>     link, then anytime I try to go to an authenticated URL, it should
>     redirect me back to the `/login` page?

Sure, that's the point of the Single Log Out mechanism - it destroys all sessions in the corresponding client applications - provided they are able to handle the logout callbacks made from CAS on `/logout`.

> - How can I tell which protocol (CAS 2.0 or SAML 1.1) I'm using? I
>     should be using whatever default CAS 4.0.0 ships with as I didn't
>     override anything in my project.

If you don't know of configuring SAML for your CAS or client application, then you definitely use the CAS protocol.

> - What is the difference between `JSESSIONID` and `CASTGC`? How are
>     they handled/used different by the server?

The `CASTGC` cookie is the holder of the identifier of your CAS session (sessions, technically tickets, are managed by CAS in its own Map-like structures). This is the secret only you and the CAS server know. The `JSESSIONID` cookie is used by Java applications to identify your application session, as defined by the [Java Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) specification. Specifically, CAS uses it mainly for keeping track of your current singing-in process.

> - Do I need to configure anything in `cas-servlet.xml` to get single
>     sign out working? If so, what? If not, what is this file used for?

No, you don't. But you might read e. g. the [official Apereo documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html) that describes the principles and possible customizations of the SLO functionality on the server side.